# What does 'celestial' mean in the TV series Deadwood?

Tags: deadwood

What does 'celestial' mean in the TV series Deadwood? Although they are always referring to Chinese, but I need to know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It refers to the Celestial Empire - a name once used to refer to China; and used as [probably] a derogatory term to refer to Chinese immigrants to the US.

Ref: [Wikipedia - Celestial Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_Empire)